# Formatting OSM Data For Use in ESRI Address Locator

Tags: arcgis-server, openstreetmap, geocoding

I've been given the task of researching the possibility of setting up an ArcGIS Geocoding Service that can work with OSM data.

I am aware of Nominatim, but since these service(s) will be running on Windows Server 2008, and the customer has already invested big $$ on the ArcGIS Server license - I don't think its going to be an option.  From what I've read, installing Nominatim on Windows is a daunting task in itself.  If someone knows of any tutorials of how to accomplish this, please let me know.

I am far from an expert in either geocoding or OSM, but I would think the biggest barrier to using OSM data in an ESRI address locator is lack of address ranges.

Is there any way at all to get address ranges for a given OSM road segment?  Any other tips or suggestions welcome.

Comment: So your customer/client spend lots on hardware/licenses but nothing on data?

Answer (score 1):

**Using LeafletJS with ArcGIS Server attribute query, Nominatim geocoder and jQuery**

> "The little tool that I built was simply a search tool for addresses
>   in my area. The addresses come from the local city government’s ArcGIS
>   Server REST endpoint for taxlots in our area. The attribute query
>   loads a search/autocomplete box, which lists available addresses
>   similar to what the user enters. Then, when it gets a result, it uses
>   the Nominatim geocoder to geocode the address, which is then displayed
>   on the map. "

- Search for address
- Geocode address
- Map the address

Full Credit to David Renz
http://blog.davidrenz.com/?p=994